# .NET Core API not accessible using secured link (i.e. https://......). Same API is accessible when accessing it with unsecured link (i.e. http://....)

Tags: c#, .net, rest, api, .net-core

I've a .NET Core Controller API.

- When accessing the Web Method(s) through secured link, i.e. https:///api/values, it's not working
- If I'm accessing it with unsecured link, i.e. http:///api/values, it's working fine.

Please let me know if I need to do something into my Startup.cs or appsettings.json

**Sample Code to access the API:**

```
try
        {

            string serviceUrl= "https://domainname/api/values";


            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(serviceUrl).Result;
            string stringData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it's not working`?

Comment: Hello Chetan,

Thanks for your reply.

It's throwing exception when trying to access it.

Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Regards, Ashish

Comment: Are you using `IIS` to browse your code locally? because if that is the case then `http` makes sense.

Comment: Write `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` as first line in `try` block

Comment: I'm publishing my code on Azure.

After publish, if I'm making my application secured i.e. https

- When I'm trying to access it (through a client app. in my case it's VSTO Add-In), throws exception.


- If I'm not securing the application/ site and accessing it, it's working.

Comment: Chetan it worked. Thanks for your input. As suggested by you I added following lines before invoking my api call ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Answer (score 1):

Adding ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

solves the issue and I get the data back from my .NET Core API.

***Note***: I was facing issue in accessing .NET Core Controller API through Miscrosoft Word VSTO-AddIn

```cs
try
        {
            /*This is the Line I added and it makes my .NET Core API Accessible in my VSTO-AddIn  */
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            string serviceUrl= "https://domainname/api/values";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(serviceUrl).Result;
            string stringData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```